# How to write a method to get a value in seconds and print in Hours, Minutes and Seconds

Tags: c#

Ok, so this was my first question on StackOverflow, I see the comments haven't been great (and the post keeps getting deleted before I have had a chance to fix it). Give me a chance! My understanding was the question should be as direct as possible and not create 'discussions'?

This is what I have tried already, but the output is not what I expect

```
int secondsToHours(seconds) {

int totalSec = seconds;
int hrs = totalSec % 3600;
int secs = totalSec % 60;
int mins = totalSec / 60;

string result = hrs + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TimeSpan struct:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
```

And then build string you want:

```
ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object

```
int seconds = 104700;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds);
Console.WriteLine("Days:" + ts.Days + 
                  ", Hours:" + ts.Hours + 
                  ", Minutes:" + ts.Minutes + 
                  ", Seconds:" + ts.Seconds );
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the TimeSpan class

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(total seconds here);
```

Then look at the Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds properties, or the TotalDays, TotalHours etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to subtract from `totalSec`. For `4700` as example;

```
int left;

int hrs = totalSec / 3600; // hrs will be 1
left = totalSec - hrs * 3600; //left will be 1100
int mins = left / 60; //mins will be 18
left = left - mins * 60; // left will be 20
int secs = left; // secs will be 20
```

As a solution, `4700` will be 1 hours, 18 minutes and 20 seconds.

But using [`TimeSpan` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be better such a case. You can use [`TimeSpan(Int32, Int32, Int32)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds);
int hrs = ts.Hours; // 1
int mins = ts.Minutes; // 18
int secs = ts.Seconds; // 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be using `TimeSpan` as already suggested in previous answer but also you could try this if you want to do it using `Math`:

```
private static void secondsToHours(int seconds)
{
    int hrs = seconds / 3600;
    int remainder = seconds % 3600;
    int mins = remainder / 60;
    int secs = seconds % 60;

    string result = hrs + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```